# Use CloudFlare to CDN a Google Cloud Storage Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-storage, cdn, cloudflare

I've heard many good things about Cloudflare, and they have an excellent CDN product that features functionality not found on competitors (HTTP2, IPv6 etc).

I have files in a Google Cloud Storage bucket.

How to set these files as the origin for a Cloudflare CDN?

(The Cloudflare control panel seems to just want a website on a root domain...?)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Maybe a bit late, but I put my answer just in case it is useful for someone else looking to do the same thing.

I have a bucket in Google Cloud Storage behind CloudFlare. You just need to follow the instructions here:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration

In CloudFlare you will need to manage your root domain, but then you can create a subdomain just for your bucket in Google Cloud Storage (don't forget to enable CloudFlare features on that subdomain). I think that's the way CloudFlare works, managing your root domain and I don't think you can avoid it.

If you need specific settings for the subdomain used for your bucket, you can use page rules in CloudFlare. For example, I had to use them because Google Cloud Storage does not support SSL but my pages using those static files were on SSL, so I had specific settings for that subdomain to use flexible SSL.

Comment: This worked perfectly to host some larger files (too big to be static files in my App engine instance) behind Cloudflare caching. Thank you!

Comment: I'm definitely late here. However, GCP now also supports HTTPS and you can also upload the Origin Certificate from Cloudflare (valid for your domain, for 15 years)

Comment: keep in mind GCP now supports SSL but ...... it costs $16/month to host a GCP load balancer needed to enable cloud storage SSL. Booo.