# Using Cloudflare CDN + HTTPS with Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, cloudflare

I’m trying to figure out how to get my Google Cloud Storage bucket to work with Cloudflare. I followed the steps here https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website and did the following:

1. Added a cname record for where I want to serve my content: cdn.test.stellarguard.me -> c.storage.googleapis.com
2. Added a cloud storage bucket for cdn.test.stellarguard.me
3. Uploaded a file and made it public: https://storage.googleapis.com/cdn.test.stellarguard.me/logo.svg

However, when I go to https://cdn.test.stellarguard.me/logo.svg I see an error that there’s an SSL version mismatch. This is probably because of what is mentioned here (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website#https):

> While you can serve your content through HTTPS using direct URI’s such
>   as , when hosting a static website using a CNAME redirect, Cloud
>   Storage only supports HTTP. To serve your content through a custom
>   domain over SSL, set up a load balancer, use a third-party Content
>   Delivery Network with Cloud Storage, or serve your static website
>   content from Firebase Hosting instead of Cloud Storage.

So I did a little searching and saw someone suggested turning on Flexible SSL ([Use CloudFlare to CDN a Google Cloud Storage Bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35116278/use-cloudflare-to-cdn-a-google-cloud-storage-bucket)), so I added a Page Rule:

`*cdn.test.stellarguard.me/*` - SSL - Flexible

However, the error still persists. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My issue had nothing to do with Google Cloud Storage https -- the issue was that CloudFlare free does not support more than one subdomain. Switching it to cdn-test.stellarguard.me worked.